# Why does the countBreak() function keep updating and not the countdown() function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want the two functions of my timer to keep running one after the other, the countdown() function runs once and the countBreak() function continually runs, would you be kind to explain why it's happening that way and how to work it out and how to pause the 'sessionCount div' when clicked? This just the part of the code that I have challenge with.

```js
var timeCount; // to hold the timer
function countdown() {
  var sessionData = countSession.textContent;
  sessionData--;
  document.getElementById('sessionCount').innerHTML = sessionData; //updating the content of session count
  timeCount = setTimeout('countdown()', 1000); //to start the timer
  if (sessionData < 0) {
    clearTimeout(timeCount);
    countBreak();
  }
}

//function to countdown breaklength
function countBreak() {
    var breakCount = breakDisplay.textContent;
    document.getElementById('sessionCount').innerHTML = breakCount; //updating the content of session count
    breakCount--;
    timeCount = setTimeout('countdown()', 1000); //to start the timer
    if (breakCount < 0) {
      clearTimeout(timeCount);
      countdown();
    }
  }
  //add eventListening to the div sessionCount
countSession.addEventListener('click', countdown, false);
```

```html
<div id='displayBreak'></div>
<button type='button' id='minusButton'>minus</button>
<!--decreases the stored variable-->
<button type='button' id='plusButton'>plus</button>
<!--increses the stored variable-->
<div id='displaySession'></div>
<button type='button' id='minusSession'>minus</button>
<!--decreases the stored variable-->
<button type='button' id='plusSession'>plus</button>
<!--increses the stored variable-->
<div id='sessionCount'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the function definition as the first paramenter of setTimeout, not the function call as a string.

```
timeCount = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
```

instead of

```
timeCount = setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
```

Comment: I did but it's pretty much the same, it's still not doing what I asked, should I give you the complete code to have a good picture? am an improving beginner in JavaScript, thank you.